# Eclipse "JSF View Validator" keeps validating without completion

Tags: eclipse, jsf

I have a project which is developed in JSF and JDBC. When I import the project into Eclipse Indigo, then the workspace has a lot of errors because the workspace keeps on validating and there is no completion.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Indigo is more than 2.5 years old already. Why don't you try to upgrade to Juno? Big chance that this Eclipse bug is then also fixed.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response i tried with Eclipse Kepler which is latest same problem i was faced.